# Laravel session key changing the whole time?

Tags: session, laravel-4

I am using "file storage" for my session. When I run this:

```
Session::set('awesomekey', 'myVal123');
```

And refresh the page, I can see new files being created in /storage/session each time. I assumed it would update the same file each time. This basically means sessions don't work at all. In other words, if it keeps recreating a session file, this never works:

```
Session::get('awesomekey');
```

Or at least, it returns a blank. What am I missing that could possibly be causing a new session key to be created each time a page is loaded?

**UPDATE**

On further investigation, it seems the cookie is regenerated on each page load. What could be causing that?

I am not even looking at logging in yet, so this information is useless to me --> http://willworkforbanjos.com/2014/02/laravel-sessions-not-working-in-4-1/

My problem is happening when I simply put the above set and get code in the master.blade.php file. It should set it, store the info, and on the next reload get the right information from session. But it can't because on reload it changed the cookie to some other code.

Anyone know why this is happening?

**UPDATE 2**

1. Adding: 'lifetime' => 120 to session.php did not work. (@Sheikh Heera)
2. Placing the code in the controller only, does not work. (@Phill Sparks)
3. I tried chrome and firefox, same result (@The Shift Exchange)

Just to be clear on what I'm trying to do. I add the following code in HomeController.php:

```
public function index()
{
    Session::put('awesomekey', 'myVal123');
    return View::make('home.index');
}
```

Then I put this in my master.blade.php:

```
print Session::get('awesomekey');
```

I do not include any "dies" or random echos in my controller side of the code, except for this. When I open the file the first time, I can see myVal123 being printed out.

I then take out this part in the controller:

```
Session::put('awesomekey', 'myVal123');
```

And reload the page. It now prints nothing. I can see in my browser that the cookie has changed. Generating a new cookie will lose the reference to the session, so I'm stuck trying to understand why it's doing that each time, even though it saves the session on the first load.

Any more ideas?

**UPDATE 3**

I also tried:

1. Running "php artisan dump-autoload" ... still doesn't work
2. I went here: http://www.whatismybrowser.com/are-cookies-enabled ... and yes, cookies are enabled.

I'm really running out of ideas here...

**UPDATE 4**

1. I went to SessionManager.php and just underneath this:

   $lifetime = $this->app['config']['session.lifetime'];

I printed out the value of life time:

```
print $lifetime; die();
```

And this code was never hit on page reload?! However, adding this in my controller:

```
$d = Config::get('session.lifetime');
print $d;
```

Does in fact print out my value for lifetime.... :(

Comment: Try using session flash, it will only work for the next request , unless you reflash it

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate? My problem is that my cookies are getting regenerated and I need to understand why?

Comment: Can you post more related code ?

Comment: Have you tried to store something in the session from your controller rather than from your view?

Comment: Have you tried on a different browser/computer to see if the problem happens then? Your not in 'private browser' mode or something?

Comment: I will provide more information tonight so as to reply to all of your queries. Unfortunately, I don't have the code with me right now.

Comment: Do you have 'secure' => false set in your session.php config file?

Comment: Also - does this problem occur on a blank install of Laravel 4.1?

Comment: I'm going to revert to my branch to a blank install and report back in a bit.

Comment: I reverted to two versions back and now sessions work. So something I added broke it. Will keep fishing til I find it.

Comment: Have you fixed it? I have the same issue. Working good in local but not in server. Please advice.

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem for me was that the cookie name in laravel must only consist of alphabet characters. I had a fullstop in mine. See my answer below (I ended up answering my own question).

Comment: For anyone still having this issue, if you are using Auth it was modified in laravel 4.1 Auth::login() causes the session to be regenerated. Revising the Auth implementation solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
'cookie' => 'xxxx.com',
```

in session.php. Apparently it loses the cookie if you have a "." in the cookie name. I can't believe Laravel doesn't like that. Or maybe it's browser's in general.

Comment: Is it the same problem with an underscore ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But try and confirm?

Comment: I removed the underscore. But I'm still having the problem.
Every load of the page create a new session without expiring the old ones.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using:

```
'lifetime' => 0 // number of minutes
```

in your `app/config/session.php` file. Make it something like this:

```
'lifetime' => 120 // number of minutes or whatever you want
```

It'll work. I tried same settings as you described and just used `0` and I get same result, each time a new file is being created but once I change it to `120` or so, it works. So, it make sense that, if it's set to `'lifetime' => 0` in the session config then every time it just creates a new file for a new session because the session doesn't live. So, go to your `app/config/session.php` file and you'll find something like this, change the value:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/
```

### Update:

You may use following code to get the `lifetime` value set in the `app/config/session.php` file:

```
Config::get('session.lifetime');
```

Comment: I can't confirm now, because the setup where this is happening is on another Laptop, but i'm 99.999% sure I did set this value. What else could be doing this?

Comment: It happened to me as well after I setup same way you described with `0` lifetime. All the best :-)

Comment: *crossing fingers* that's the problem. will see tonight.

Comment: This doesn't work. I have my "lifetime" set as 'lifetime' => 1440

Comment: This did not work. i am updating the ticket with more info now.

Comment: Must session.php maybe be included somehow in another file? I searched for session.php across the codebase and don't see it being included anywhere?

Comment: Is there a way to print out the global value for lifetime to make sure that it's getting registered?

Comment: This happens during the boot up process of the framework and all the class loading is done via `autoloader` class so, it's handled by the framework.

Comment: I am able to print out the lifetime value in the controller. So it something else causing the cookie to change. I honestly don't know what else to look at anymore.

Comment: What is your configuration and what third party packages you have installed ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the cookie's expire time in Chrome developer tools, or Firebug. If it is set to 0 then the cookie will expire immediately.

Also, double-check if your clock is setup correctly - strange things could happen if there's a disparity between your host's and the browser's clock. Make both systems consult NTP to ensure this is not an issue.

Comment: Also look to see if this is not an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21835934/401467

Comment: This did help. Every time I load the page, it says the cookie's expire time is NOW. So, my "lifetime" variable is somehow being overridden. I'm also going through all my commits to see if a random "echo" or "print" hasn't been left inbetween any of the code. The search continues...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with the sessions, if you're using the model User and your users table  doesn't have the primaryKey as Id, you must overwrite that variable at the model.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

     protected $primaryKey = 'admin_id';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In /app/config/session.php check the "HTTPS Only Cookie" setting.

Make sure it's "secure => false" if you are not using SSL!

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced issues related to this. The session file wasn't created every time but sometimes I just can't get the session variable displayed. After hours of experiments I found that the problem was related to [Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

If you're using Debugbar and having session issues, disable it and try again to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Use Session::put('value') instead of set.

http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-usage

Comment: Thanks for showing the difference, but this made no difference

Comment: This isn't the issue, `Session::put()` uses `Session::set()` https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L329